# Makefile: dependencies on directory content when creating a tar file

Tags: dependencies, directory, makefile, tar

In my battle against `.PHONY` targets I re-wrote:

```
# Makefile v0

tar:
    tar -cf tarfile.tar dir

.PHONY: tar
```

to be:

```
# Makefile v1

tar: tarfile.tar

tarfile.tar: $(shell find dir)
    tar -cf $@ dir

.PHONY: tar
```

Which seems to work for a toy example.

However, I can see that this might do the wrong thing, depending on the time when `$(shell find dir)` is evaluated. If there is some rule that will create or delete files in `dir` after the Makefile is parsed, this might break.

---

**Update**

Based on @user562374's answer, I seem to have a better solution, but consider this case:

```
# Makefile v2

tar: tarfile.tar

tarfile.tar: dir/.dirstamp
    tar --create --exclude $< --file $@ $(<D)

dir/.dirstamp: .FORCE
    [ ! -e $@ -o "$(find $(@D) -newer $@ -print -quit)" ] && touch $@

dir/a: src/a
    cp $< $@

.FORCE:
.PHONY: .FORCE tar
```

Now suppose `src/a` has been changed. Since there is no dependency between `tarfile.tar` and `dir/a` (not direct nor indirect), the `tarfile.tar:` target might be evaluated before `dir/a:`, and thus `tarfile.tar` will not be up-to-date.

---

So, my questions are: What is the best practice of dealing with such cases? Must I maintain the list of files in `dir` separately? If so what is the easiest way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

That is how I would use it.

```
.PHONY: .FORCE
.FORCE:

dirstamp: .FORCE
        hxdirstamp subdir/ >$@.tmp; \
        cmp -s $@ $@.tmp || mv $@.tmp $@; \
        rm -f $@.tmp;

my.tar: dirstamp
        tar -cf $@ subdir/;
```

You can also use `ls -Rl` instead for dirstamping, but be aware that it is subject to influence from the locale, permission and size changes (all of which, were it just a make dependency, would be ignored).

Comment: Nice. Based on this answer, a collègue came up with an optimized recipe for the `dirstamp` target: `[ ! -e $@ -o "$(find subdir/ -newer $@ -print -quit)" ] && touch $@`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just mark `tarfile.tar` as `.PHONY` when `dir/` contains files newer than it?

```
$(if $(shell find dir -type f -newer file.tar),$(eval .PHONY: file.tar))
file.tar: ; tar cvf $@ dir/
```

(Maybe `! -type d` would be a tad better than `-type f`, but you get the idea.)

Comment: why do you think this is any better then `Makefile v2`? How does it solve the failure when `src/a` has been changed? Also please note that I *deliberately* did not limit the find results to `type f` (or `! -type d`), to support add/remove files from sub-directories of `dir`.

Comment: True, it is very similar to Makefile v1. In fact I prefer the v1 two-liner to my suggestion above. V2 is simply broken. In v2 you have not told make that executing the recipe for `dir/a` will make it necessary to run the recipe for `tarfile.tar`. It is nastily fragile and will silently fail under -jn for some values of _n_ (also you need to double the `$` on the find expression: `$$(find...)`).